# Command Pattern example confusion

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I am going through the Head-First Design Pattern book when I came across the "Command Pattern" chapter. I have recreated the example in Playground:

```
protocol RemoteActions {
    func turnOn()
}

protocol Product {
    var description: String { get set }
}

struct Light: Product {
    var description: String
    // some other properties
}

struct Heater: Product {
    var description: String
    // some other properties
}

class LightOn: RemoteActions {

    var light: Light

    init(light: Light) {
        self.light = light
    }

    func turnOn() {
        print("\(light.description) on")
    }
}

class HeaterOn: RemoteActions {

    var heater: Heater

    init(heater: Heater) {
        self.heater = heater
    }

    func turnOn() {
        print("\(heater.description) on")
    }
}


class Remote {
    func doAction(action: RemoteActions) {
        action.turnOn()
    }
}

let r = Remote()
let l = Light(description: "light1")
let h = Heater(description: "heater1")
let lo = LightOn(light: l)
let ho = HeaterOn(heater: h)
r.doAction(action: lo)
r.doAction(action: ho)
```

I mean what are the benefits of this pattern?? Yes, I can see that the remote will only know about its actions, but what if I wanted to create a new Product to be turned on and off? I will undoubtfully have to create a new "Command Class" right? Which makes this part in the book really silly:

[image: image from textbook]

Wouldn't it be better if we conformed the action into said Product? Like this:

```
protocol RemoteActions {
    func turnOn()
}

protocol Product: RemoteActions {
    var description: String { get set }
    func turnOn()
}

struct Light: Product {
    var description: String
    // some other properties
    func turnOn() {
        print("\(description) on")
    }
}

struct Heater: Product {
    var description: String
    // some other properties
    func turnOn() {
        print("\(description) on")
    }
}

class Remote {
    func doAction(product: Product) {
        product.turnOn()
    }
}

let r = Remote()
let l = Light(description: "light1")
let h = Heater(description: "heater1")

r.doAction(product: l)
r.doAction(product: h)
```

Answer (score 0):

[gof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) says: 'The Command pattern lets toolkit objects make requests of unspecified application objects by turning the request itself into an object. This object can be stored and passed around like other objects. The key to this pattern is an abstract Command class, which declares an interface for executing operations. In the simplest form this interface includes an abstract Execute operation. Concrete Command subclasses specify a receiver-action pair by storing the receiver as an instance variable and by implementing Execute to invoke the request. The receiver has the knowledge required to carry out the request.'

Comment: but what are the benefits of this kind of pattern? Like I said above, I'd have to create each action as a subclass whenever I need one, thus creating A LOT of classes? Or is there a specific use case on this pattern?

Comment: suppose you were writing an editor where you insert and delete text and you need to be able to undo or redo for many levels.